# Subscribing to the same observable (shared) from different components with params

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

I have two components on the same page. Each component is displaying stuff regarding orders subscribing to an `Observable` coming from a service with parameters.

The service:

```
getOrders(url: string, query: string) : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(url + "&" + query, this.options)
                        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'))
                        .share();

    }
```

Component 1:

```
    Observable.combineLatest(this.behaviorsubject1,this.behaviorsubject2)
    .subscribe((res)=>{
                this.combineLatestStream = res;
                this.selectedOrganization = this.combineLatestStream[1];

                this.mainService$ = this.orderService.getOrders(this.settings.backend.orders, "organization_id="+this.selectedOrganization.organization_id);
                this.mainService$.subscribe(result => {
                //call 1
                });

    });
```

Component 2:

```
  this.aservice.stuff.subscribe((res) => {
    this.selectedOrganization = res;
    this.mainService$ = this.orderService.getOrders(this.settings.backend.orders, "organization_id="+this.selectedOrganization.organization_id+"&status=1");
    this.mainService$.subscribe((val) => {
       //call 2
    })
  })
```

In first component I get all the orders; In the second component I get only some of them (based on some parameters); both with `mainService$`. I will have more components that will need to subscribe to this service. Sharing the service is not working. Any other methods?

I tried with `publishReplay(1).refCount()` too. I don't want to have multiple API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http observable completes after subscribe, if you want that all subscriber will be notified you need to use BehaviorSubject and call on getOrders behaviorSubject.next():

**Example:**

```
behaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(<Orders[]>{}) 

getOrders(url: string, query: string) : void {
        this.http.get(url + "&" + query, this.options)
                        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'))
                        .do((orders) => behaviorSubject.next(orders))
                        .subscribe();

    }
```

Comment: Using `void` won't work. And how can I get the data now in components?

Comment: Yeah, just figured out the typo. Ok, I understand what you wanted to explain but how can I get the data in components. `this.mainService$` it's `undefined` now..